# Sitecore Search API can't find anything in string field

Tags: solr, sitecore

I have some strange issue with Search Context. 
I am geting 0 results from query in case d.Path.StartsWith exist.

I see that path field is contain full path and it is correct in index/ I want to find field witch is start from some sitecore path, but no luck.
I am using Solr at backend.

```cs
string path = "/sitecore/blabla"; //just for example
var contextIndex = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_master_index");
using (var context = contextIndex.CreateSearchContext())
{
    var results = context.GetQueryable<PackageDateDocument>()
                .Where(d => (d.TemplateName == _templatename) && (d.Language == "en") && (d.Path.StartsWith(path)));
    return results;
}
```

what is wrong with my query ?

Update 1:
My Solr version is 4.4.0
Seems like it is related to / char
If use Solr UI next query works in case add / chars

```
"q": "_fullpath:\\/sitecore\\/content\\/system\\/balabla* && _language: \"en\" && _templatename: \"My Template\"",
```

Comment: does your PackageDateDocument class inherits from SearchResultItem?

Comment: @SitecoreClimber yes it does. public class PackageDateDocument : SearchResultItem

Comment: Just a silly idea but did you try with `string path = "/sitecore/blabla"`?

Comment: @Gatogordo my bad it should be / in example

Comment: Try to use lowercase of both `_templatename` and `path`

Comment: @MarekMusielak ok, but directly in solr I see _templatename in normal way

Answer (score 1):

Ok, Sitecore support told me that this issue was fixed in Sitecore 8 SP3 ))) 
it is some issue with solr string inside
they recommend use item ID and Paths field in query.

```
var results = context.GetQueryable<PackageDateDocument>()
                    .Where(d => (d.TemplateName == _templatename)
                            && (d.Language == rootTour.Language.Name) && d.Paths.Contains(item.ID));
```

Answer (score 0):

"/" char should be escaped in your query. This should have already addressed in the latest Sitecore versions. 
For earlier versions, it is recommended to use Contains for paths.